# При конвертировании BGR в HSV через OpenCV ломается цвет

Tags: python, opencv

Оригинал и результат:

[image: оригинал]

[image: p]

Код используемый для преобразования:

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread("bl.png")
image = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(image), cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
```

Как исправить?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42761838/5741205

Answer (score 3):

Краткий перевод [ответа @user7678894](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42761838/5741205):

Нет смысла рисовать изображение, преобразованное к `HSV` формату, используя `cv2.imshow()`.

`imshow()` рассчитывает, что ему передали изображение (матрицу) в формате `BGR`.

Чтобы вывести `HSV` изображение на экран, используя `cv2.imshow()`, это изображение нужно сначала преобразовать к `BGR`:

```
cv2.imshow('', cv2.cvtColor(im_hsv, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]